# Update/Add labels to Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster Workloads through Python API

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Has anyone tried to add or update the Clusters from Google Kubernetes Engine through Python API?

I managed to do this for Compute instances, but the guide for Kubernetes Engine says its deprecated:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters.nodePools/update

Tried it and it fails saying it does not find "labels":

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/testingproject/zones/us-east1/clusters/testing-cluster/resourceLabels?alt=json
> returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "labels": Cannot
> find field.". Details: "[{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
> [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
> "labels": Cannot find field.'}]}]">

My code is this:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Deprecated. The Google Developers Console [project ID or project
# number](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#projectnumber).
# This field has been deprecated and replaced by the name field.
project_id = 'testingproject'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# Deprecated. The name of the Google Compute Engine
# [zone](/compute/docs/zones#available) in which the cluster
# resides.
# This field has been deprecated and replaced by the name field.
zone = 'us-east1'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# Deprecated. The name of the cluster.
# This field has been deprecated and replaced by the name field.
cluster_id = 'testing-cluster'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

set_labels_request_body = {
    'labels': 'value'
}

request = service.projects().zones().clusters().resourceLabels(projectId=project_id, zone=zone, clusterId=cluster_id, body=set_labels_request_body)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

I want to update the Workload named 'matei-testing-2000-gke-ops' inside the cluster 'testing-cluster'.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Update: It does not find the labels because the name is resourceLabels. But I get the following error after:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects//zones//clusters//resourceLabels?alt=json
> returned "Invalid value at 'resource_labels'
> (type.googleapis.com/google.container.v1.SetLabelsRequest.ResourceLabelsEntry),
> "value"". Details: "[{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
> [{'field': 'resource_labels', 'description': 'Invalid value at
> 'resource_labels'
> (type.googleapis.com/google.container.v1.SetLabelsRequest.ResourceLabelsEntry),
> "value"'}]}]">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've <strike>not</strike> now tried this.

But IIUC, you'll need to:

- <strike>ditch (or use defaults) for e.g. `project_id`, `zone` and `cluster_id` parameters of `resourceLabels`</strike>
- add `name` to your body and it should be of the form: `projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*`

i.e.

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

PROJECT = os.getenv("PROJECT")
LOCATION = os.getenv("ZONE")
CLUSTER = os.getenv("CLUSTER")

NAME = "projects/{project}/locations/{location}/clusters/{cluster}".format(
        project=project_id,
        location=zone,
        cluster=cluster_id)


# To update `resourceLabels` you must first fingerprint them
# To get the current `labelFingerprint`, you must `get` the cluster

body = {
    'name': NAME,
}

request = service.projects().zones().clusters().get(
    projectId=project_id,
    zone=zone,
    clusterId=cluster_id)
response = request.execute()

labelFingerprint = response["labelFingerprint"]

if "resourceLabels" in response:
    print("Existing labels")
    resourceLabels = response["resourceLabels"]
else:
    print("No labels")
    resourceLabels = {}

# Add|update a label
resourceLabels["dog"] = "freddie"

# Construct `resourceLabels` request
body = {
    'name': NAME,
    'resourceLabels': resourceLabels,
     'labelFingerprint': labelFingerprint,
}

request = service.projects().zones().clusters().resourceLabels(
    projectId=project_id,
    zone=zone,
    clusterId=cluster_id,
    body=body)

# Do something with the `response`
response = request.execute()
```

- [`clusters.get`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/get)
- [`clusters#CLuster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster)

And

```sh
gcloud container clusters describe ${CLUSTER} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(labelFingerprint,resourceLabels)"
```

Before:

```sh
a9dc16a7
```

After:

```sh
b2c32ec0    dog=freddie
```

Comment: The thing is, this will update the Cluster itself right? How do I add/update labels on specific workloads? Maybe based on their namespaces or name?

Comment: Also the above gives me the same type of error: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects//zones//clusters//resourceLabels?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "labels": Cannot find field.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "labels": Cannot find field.'}]}]">

Comment: My bad, I assumed you had the correctly.... I'll update the answer. If you follow the documentation, it shows you how to create `resourceLabels`.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I update the resource labels on the workloads of the cluster?

Comment: It turns out that the 'deprecated' values are **still** required, I've updated the code. The code that I included in my answer shows you how to update the labels. If `resourceLabels` exist on the cluster, you just update these.